# Connection timeout to local JBoss 7.2.0 on osx

Tags: osx-lion, jboss7.x

I'm attempting to connect to a locally deployed JBoss 7.2.0 on osx, but I get the following error message when trying to connect with the CLI:

```
$ bin/jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
The controller is not available at localhost:9999: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
[disconnected /]
```

Netstat shows:

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9999         *.*                    LISTEN
```

and the server log states:

```
16:24:37,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
```

In addition to which, I can telnet to 127.0.0.1:9999 (though the connection dies due to incorrect packet size, which I presume is as intended).

I've verified that standalone.xml states 127.0.0.1 as the correct binding address and 9999 as the correct port for *management-native*.

Is there anything I've missed, or any other way to trouble shoot?

Comment: This seems to be a possible culprit though: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7159361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7159361) in OpenJDK turned out to be it.